# How does one create a __unicode__ field that the Admin system can sort?

Tags: python, django, sorting, unicode

I am using Django to run a small patient list. In the admin interface I have a few columns that are defined in an admin.py file.

```
class InpatientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_filter = ['discharged','date_of_admission']
date_hierarchy = 'date_of_admission'
list_display = ('room', '__unicode__', 'date_of_admission', 'date_of_discharge', 'discharged')
inlines = [ EncounterInline ]
```

The unicode field is defined in the model as

```
    def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s, %s %s' % (self.last_name, self.first_name, self.DOB)
```

The admin interface works. Really slick stuff the Django programmers did. However, when I click on the heading for the unicode defined field it will not sort. I can sort the Room, date_of_admission, and date_of_discharge, but the unicode field will not sort. I tried just returning self.last_name in the unicode def, but that also didn't work.  I suspect that the unicode field does not provide a hook back to a comparison routine.

I'm sure there is something simple to make this work, but I don't know the terms to google with to find the solution. Help appreciated.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 2):

Tried to use Peter DeGlopper's answer, but there are a couple of issues, that snippet should go in models.py, but there is no `self` defined in the model.

Thus,

```
self.__unicode__.admin_order_field = 'last_name'
```

won't work.

Even if you try:

```
__unicode__.admin_order_field = 'last_name'
```

Admin is stubborn and doesn't want to sort. Thus, I found [this solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/J13pCP2W1cI). That is to create a model method that just returns the unicode name and then defines the sort field.

Again, not my solution (code is from the link), but it should help others facing the same problem:

**models.py**

```
def unicode_sort(self):
    return self.__unicode__()

unicode_sort.admin_order_field = 'sort'
unicode_sort.short_description = u'name'
```

**admin.py**

```
list_display = ('unicode_sort',)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to sort by a single field (say, `last_name`) you can set that as the `admin_order_field` for your `__unicode__` method. More complex sorting by callable fields is not supported.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/

> Usually, elements of list_display that aren’t actual database fields can’t be used in sorting (because Django does all the sorting at the database level).
>
> However, if an element of `list_display` represents a certain database field, you can indicate this fact by setting the `admin_order_field` attribute of the item.

So this should work, as long as the logic is what you want:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s, %s %s' % (self.last_name, self.first_name, self.DOB)
self.__unicode__.admin_order_field = 'last_name'
```